# How to autofill support email in the GCP project

Tags: firebase, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I’m creating the GCP project using this method https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/create. As I understand this method doesn’t allow fill the Support email for the project.

Please, advise me, what other options are there to fill the support email automatically through the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer here is that currently the creation or submission of the email address for support portal use is not supported using the projects.create methods of the API... The full list of all methods for the API are listed in this documentation[1](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects#create).You can always file a feature by following the instructions contained here[2](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests)